# c:\...\source\repos\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.exe (process 3764) exited with code 0

Tags: c++, ide, termination

I have a little issue with my first time programming.
I get that message [image: printscreen]

is that ok to get "c:\users\amittler\source\repos\HelloWorld..."?

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it's OK to get this.

Your IDE is just telling you that the program finished running. And I presume that all your program does is printing "Hello World!", so it's finishing a split second after that.

> "c:\users\amittler\source\repos\HelloWorld..."?

This is the location of your program. When your IDE is done building it, it has to put it somewhere before it can run it, and that's where it went.

> (process 3764)

Your computer can do many things (seemingly) at once, and all these things running at the same time get a process number. It's basically an identification. It's telling you the process number that your program run had. Most of the time, you won't be needing this information.

> exited with code 0

This means that your program has ran successfully. Actually, it's dependent on what you `return` in your `main` function. The convention is that `0` stands for success and everything else denotes an error. For instance, if a different program was calling your program and got a `0` back it knows it went well, otherwise it might react accordingly.